# RPi2 bare metal blinker

Tags: bare-metal, assembly

This is my first assembly program. I have a FAT32 formatted SD card with latest `bootcode.bin`, `start.elf`, and a flat binary named `kernel7.img` converted from the following dumped ELF file:

```
build/kernal.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .init:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e59f0044    ldr r0, [pc, #68]   ; 804c <waitOff+0xc>
    8004:   e5901010    ldr r1, [r0, #16]
    8008:   e3a02001    mov r2, #1
    800c:   e1a02a82    lsl r2, r2, #21
    8010:   e5801010    str r1, [r0, #16]
    8014:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1
    8018:   e1a01781    lsl r1, r1, #15
    801c:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0

00008020 <loop>:
    8020:   e5801020    str r1, [r0, #32]
    8024:   e580202c    str r2, [r0, #44]   ; 0x2c
    8028:   e3a03601    mov r3, #1048576    ; 0x100000

0000802c <waitOn>:
    802c:   e2533001    subs    r3, r3, #1
    8030:   1afffffd    bne 802c <waitOn>
    8034:   e580102c    str r1, [r0, #44]   ; 0x2c
    8038:   e5802020    str r2, [r0, #32]
    803c:   e3a03601    mov r3, #1048576    ; 0x100000

00008040 <waitOff>:
    8040:   e2533001    subs    r3, r3, #1
    8044:   1afffffd    bne 8040 <waitOff>
    8048:   eafffff4    b   8020 <loop>
    804c:   3f200000    .word   0x3f200000
```

The code uses the following addresses:

- GPIO controller base: 0x3F200000
- GPFSEL4: 0x3F200010
- GPSET1: 0x3F200020
- GPCLR1: 0x3F20002C

As far as I'm aware, the ACT led on the RPi2 is on GPIO pin 47 (where is the official documentation for this?). I can walk through this listing, and it seems to all make sense - I don't understand why nothing is happening (both ACT and PWR remain on)

Comment: Got it working: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56372/33424